# Android: Killing third a app

Tags: android, kill-process

I've a problem with killing third party apps from my application. Here's the code:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager
        .getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {

    if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
        if (appProcess.pkgList[0].equalsIgnoreCase("com.adobe.air")) {
            Log.v("ACTIVITY FOUND", "" + appProcess.pkgList[0]
                    + " - " + appProcess.pid);

            activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.adobe.air");
            activityManager.restartPackage("com.adobe.air");

            android.os.Process.killProcess(appProcess.pid);


        }
    }
}
Log.v("RUN", "----------------------------------");
```

And in AndroidManifest I added the permissions `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` and `android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES`.

In Log I can correctly read the message when the package com.adobe.air is running, but `killBackgroundProcesses`, `restartPackage` and `KillProcess` have no success force closing the app itself. What's wrong?

Comment: You must be rooted or a system app to kill other apps.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Process.killProcess(int pid) to kill processes that have
   the same UID with your App.
2. You can use
       ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName),with
       KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission in your manifest(for API >= 8)
3. or ActivityManager.restartPackage (String packageName)(for API < 8)
       to kill specified process,except of forground process.